# ASP.NET Core Razor Pages Endpoint Routing for all Paths after Page Name in URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

So, I'm adapting an MCV example to a Razor Pages application, and have everything working now except for endpoint routing.

Desired behavior:

> All text in the URL after the desired page name will be passed to that page's OnGet action as an input variable.
>
> e.g. HTTP://application.tld/Reports/Static/any/text/that/follows
> is handle by the Static.cshtml.cs page's OnGet(string viewPath)
> and passes "any/text/that/follows" as the viewPath input variable

Actual behavior:

> It tries to find a page at the full location, /Reports/Static/any/text/that/follows, which doesn't exist, so it returns a 404 error.

Using:

- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation Version="5.0.3"
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session Version="2.2.0"
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore Version="5.0.3"

In the MCV example app startup.cs:

```
            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

                //Because everything after "Explorer/" is our path and path contains
                //some slashes and maybe spaces, so we can use "Explorer/{*path}"

                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "Explorer",
                    template: "Explorer/{*path}",
                    defaults: new { controller = "Explorer", action = "Index" });
            });
```

then in the controller

```
            public IActionResult Index(string path)
```

In the Razor Pages app startup.cs:

```
            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();

                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                 name: "static",
                 pattern: "/Reports/Static/{*viewPath}",
                 defaults: new { page = "/Reports/Static", action = "OnGet" });
            });
```

then in the page

```
            public IActionResult OnGet(string viewPath)
```

Suggestions on how to get this working?

TIA :0)

---

Edit with my final solution, with much thanks to @Sergey, and with a catch-all since the number of segments will be variable:

(1) nothing needed for this in the startup.cs so I removed the "endpoints.MapControllerRoute()" section

(2) keep in the page's cshtml.cs file

```
            public IActionResult OnGet(string viewPath)
```

(3) and then add in the page's cshtml file

```
            @page "{*viewPath}"
```

Comment: Just to note: I've tried it with and without the leading slash in the pattern and new page redirect values. The same behavior results either way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use razor pages you have to put to the top of your page:

`````
@page "{any}/{text}/{that}/{follows}"
//or you can use some nullables
@page "{any}/{text?}/{that?}/{follows?}"
````
in the code behind the page in the action OnGet or OnGetAsync:
````
public async Tast<IActionResult> OnGetAsync( string any, string text, ....)
````
`````

Comment: Thanks. I just tried @page "{viewPath?}" and the behavior hasn't changed. Maybe (probably) I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: {doh!} The case of too many pages open, I put it in the wrong page. In the correct page, adding the @page "{viewPath?} works. Thanks so much!

Comment: and to add: looks like I don't need the startup.cs routing portion either. Niiiiiicce. :0)

Comment: No, you don't need anything extra in startup.